# Parallel connection to Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I use a library that acts as a repository manager in my code by providing functions to retrieve some information from an Azure Cosmos DB (`_repositoryManager` in this case). I want to improve the time performance of the following code that iterates through `listOfGroupIds` and retrieves them one by one:

```cs
foreach(var groupId in listOfGroupIds)
{
    var itemsForGroup = await _repositoryManager.GetItemsByGroupId(groupId);
    itemList.AddRange(itemsForGroup);
}
```

I am wondering if I am allowed to run them in parallel by:

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(listOfGroupIds, groupId =>
{
    var itemsForGroup = _repositoryManager.GetItemsByGroupId(groupId);
    lock (itemList)
        itemList.AddRange(itemsForGroup.Result);
});
```

by knowing the repository manager uses `CosmosClient GetConnection()`. My hesitation is I don't know if `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient()` opens a new connection for each query, or if it uses a single connection upon initialization which in the latter case, should I have concerns about the functionality of the code in cases where there are many `groupId`s and it might open many requests in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

The Cosmos client maintains connections behind the scenes and will reuse connections to your account.

If you are trying to lookup a large group of individual items, the most efficient way is to use ReadManyItemsAsync(), versus using a query or calling ReadItemAsync() in a loop.

You need both the partition key and id. You can learn more about it here, [Container.ReadManyItemsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readmanyitemsasync?view=azure-dotnet)